# Handler Message is Null

Tags: android, handler

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my code since I have two instances of a `Handler` that are, from my eyes, nearly identical and yet one returns properly and the other doesn't. In the main activity, they're called as follows:

Working

```
BingSpatialDataService bsds = new BingSpatialDataService(Constants.BingSpatialAccessId,
                                                         Constants.BingSpatialSourceName,
                                                         Constants.BingSpatialEntityTypeName,
                                                         Constants.BingSpatialQueryKey);
bsds.FindByAreaCompleted = new Handler()
{
   public void handleMessage(Message msg)
   {
      if(msg.obj != null)
      {
         // Do something with msg
      }
   }
};

bsds.FindByArea(l.Point, searchRadius, null);
```

Not Working

```
FWSDataService fds = new FWSDataService();
fds.FindByTimespanCompleted = new Handler()
{
   public void handleMessage(Message msg)
   {
      if(msg.obj != null)
      {
         // Do something with msg
      }
   }
};

fds.FindByTimespan(timespan);
```

`fds` and `bsds` are classes that contain the code for the handlers

`bsds`

```
public class BingSpatialDataService {
    public Handler FindByAreaCompleted;
    public Handler FindByIDCompleted;
    public Handler FindByPropertyCompleted;

    private String _queryKey;
    private String _serviceURL;

    public BingSpatialDataService(String accessId, String dataSourceName, String entityTypeName, String queryKey){
        _queryKey = queryKey;       
        _serviceURL = "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/" + accessId + "/" + dataSourceName + "/" + entityTypeName;
    }

    /* Public Methods */

    //http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/accessId/dataSourceName/entityTypeName?spatialFilter=nearby(latitude,longitude,distance)&queryoption1&queryoption2&queryoptionN&key=queryKey
    public void FindByArea(Coordinate center, double distance, QueryOption options){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(_serviceURL);

        //Add spatial filter
        sb.append("?spatialFilter=nearby(");
        sb.append(center.Latitude);
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(center.Longitude);
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(distance);
        sb.append(")");

        //Add Query Options
        if(options != null){
            sb.append(options.toString());
        }else{
            sb.append("&$format=json");
        }

        //Add Bing Maps Key
        sb.append("&key=");
        sb.append(_queryKey);

        //create service request
        ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest(sb.toString(), RequestType.GET, ContentTypes.JSON);
        QueryServiceAsyncTask service = new QueryServiceAsyncTask(FindByAreaCompleted);
        service.execute(request);
    }

    //http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/accessId/dataSourceName/entityTypeName?spatialFilter=bbox(southLatitude,westLongitude,northLatitude,eastLongitude)&queryOption1&queryOption2&queryOptionN)&key=queryKey
    public void FindByArea(LocationRect boundingBox, QueryOption options){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(_serviceURL);

        //Add spatial filter
        sb.append("?spatialFilter=bbox(");
        sb.append(boundingBox.getSouth());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(boundingBox.getWest());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(boundingBox.getNorth());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(boundingBox.getEast());
        sb.append(")");

        //Add Query Options
        if(options != null){
            sb.append(options.toString());
        }else{
            sb.append("&$format=json");
        }

        //Add Bing Maps Key
        sb.append("&key=");
        sb.append(_queryKey);

        //create service request
        ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest(sb.toString(), RequestType.GET, ContentTypes.JSON);
        QueryServiceAsyncTask service = new QueryServiceAsyncTask(FindByAreaCompleted);
        service.execute(request);
    }
```

`fds`

```
public class FWSDataService {
    public Handler FindByTimespanCompleted;

    private String serviceURL;

    public FWSDataService()
    {
        serviceURL = "http://10.90.32.120/fws/home/getsiterecentrainfall/?regionid=1&amp;regionid=19&amp;";
    }

    public void FindByTimespan(int timespan)
    {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sBuilder.append(serviceURL);

        // Add timespan filter
        sBuilder.append("timespan=");
        sBuilder.append(timespan);

        ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest(sBuilder.toString(), RequestType.GET, ContentTypes.JSON);
        QueryServiceAsyncTask service = new QueryServiceAsyncTask(this.FindByTimespanCompleted);
        service.execute(request);
    }

}
```

I've checked the URL for the `Handler` that's not working and the data is returned properly. In fact, I'm using the same URL elsewhere and it's working fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When you say it's not returning properly, what do you mean exactly? An exception? Any relevant logcat output?

Comment: The `msg` property of the Handler is `null`. I'll sift through the LogCat to see what I can find.

Comment: For some reason, my LogCat filter isn't working properly and I'm forced to debug this app on a device since Bing doesn't support emulators. End result? LogCat's clocking about 100 message per second and I just can't get through it.

Comment: Have you tryed calling the service with the same information? I think its the service/url that gives you problem. Can't help with that since we don't have any code from that.

Comment: @Warpzit I try, but `bsds` parts how Bing writes it and I'm stuck between following their conventions or Java conventions.

Comment: In what class are you creating your Handler objects? (And in what thread?)

Comment: They're being created in the main activity and `QueryServiceAsyncTask` processes them in a separate thread managed by the Android OS.